# symfony2 twig path links You have requested a non-existent service ""

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have such problem:

You have requested a non-existent service ""

in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php at line 264

my code

```
<p><a href="{{ path('maciej_test_about') }}">About</a></p>
```

DefaultController.php

```
<?php

namespace maciej\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
        public function aboutAction()
    {
        return $this->render('maciejTestBundle:about.html.twig');
    }
}
```

routing.yml

```
maciej_test_about:
    path:     /about
    defaults: { _controller: maciejTestBundle:about }
```

what is the problem?

Comment: First I think this is `maciejTestBundle::about.html.twig` (with two `:`) if you put the `about.html.twig` in `Resources/views` of your bundle. Don't you have anymore code?

Comment: one ":" jest ok. This isn't a problem. I have more code but a problem is with this code.

Comment: About your controller in the route, it should be `maciejTestBundle:Default:about`

Comment: It's running. Thx. I had my file in Resources/views, but i think it's good

Comment: well cool if it works.... please close your question, it has no real interest for the community. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I review your code your template path in controller is wrong.

Try this!

```
return $this->render('maciejTestBundle:Default:about.html.twig');
```